Can I configure a Virtual Network on different Service Plans?
Let say I've created MyVirtualNetwork on Azure portal (which is a VNet that link to my Service onprem using VPN gateway), within resource group MyResourceGroup1.
Can I configure it to works on app located on both MyServicePlan1 (available on MyResourceGroup1) and MyServicePlan2 (available on MyResourceGroup2)?
So different plans available on different resource group?
Is this Virtual Network object agnostic in terms of resources/plans?
